# How to add an error message to the ModelState on MVC using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, runtime-error, modelstate

This is my Model property

```
 public ModelStateDictionary modelSateClientSide { get; set; }
```

Now I called the Property in JavaScript and add the error in my ModelState

```
if (parseInt(academicAchievement, 10) > parseInt(peAcademicAchievement, 10))
{
    @Model.modelSateClientSide.AddModelError(string.Empty, "xxx");
    return false;
}
```

Am I doing it correctly? And I got a error in above line:

> The best overloaded method match for 
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments.

How can solve this? Any other option to add error message in ModelState on MVC using Javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can write to the ModelState Dictionary using JavaScript because it is a Client-Side language and C# / Razor are processed on the Server-Side.

In the code you posted, the line

```
@Model.modelSateClientSide.AddModelError(string.Empty, "xxx");
```

Will actually be evaluated every time the page loads because it is processed on the server, and Razor doesn't "know" about JavaScript or its conditional statements.

If you, however, just want to display an error message similar to what the `ValidationSummary` HtmlHelper generates by default, you can write a JavaScript function to do it. Something more or less like this:

```
function showClientError(message) {
   var $div = $('.validation-summary-errors');
   if ($div.length == 0) {
       $div = $('<div class="validation-summary-errors">');
       $div.html('<ul></ul>');
       // Put the $div somewhere
       $div.appendTo($('#myForm'));
   }
   $div.find('ul').append($('<li>').text(message));
}
```